# Angular 4 get double input file event for upload

Tags: angular, typescript, firebase, firebase-storage, angularfire2

I have two input file like shown below :

```
<input required accept=".jpg" #file (change)="coverUpload($event)" id="file" name="file" type="file" >

<input required accept=".pdf" #pdf (change)="fileUpload($event)"  id="pdfFile" name="pdfFile" type="file" >



 <button md-raised-button color="primary" type="submit" (click)="addNew()" [disabled]="!form.valid">Submit</button>
```

And Here is the ts code :

```
selectedFiles: FileList;
selectedPdf: FileList;

coverUpload(event) {
      this.selectedFiles = event.target.files;
    }

fileUpload(event) {
      this.selectedPdf = event.target.files;
    }

 addNew() {

       let fle = this.selectedFiles.item(0);
       console.log(fle.name);
       let flePdf = this.selectedPdf.item(0);
       console.log(flePdf.name);

        this.bookSrv.addBook(this.books, fle, flePdf);
         this.router.navigate(['/mybooks']);
  }
```

And Here is my BookService :

```
 addBook(bok: Book, file: File, pdfFile: File) {
            if (this.uid != undefined && this.uid != null) {
                let key = this.afd.list('books' + '/' + 'list').$ref.ref.push().key;
                let userid = this.afAuth.auth.currentUser.uid;
                this.firebasestorage.ref(`books` + `/` + key + `/` + this.currentUserId + bok.bookname).put(file).then(
                this.firebasestorage.ref(`books` + `/` + key + `/` + this.currentUserId + bok.bookname).put(pdfFile).then(
                    snapshot => {
                        bok.icon = snapshot.downloadURL;
                        bok.pdf = snapshot.downloadURL;       
                        this.afd.object('books/list' + '/' + key + this.currentUserId).set(bok);
                    }));

            }
        }
```

After I submitted into firebase it just upload the last file, How to make it upload both file, thanks.

Comment: i think you should  post the code  for uploading to firebase too..... which format you send the image is it base64?..... have you checked what's the value printed when doing console.log()?

Comment: Okay thanks @JoseKj I've updated my code

Comment: ok i will check

Comment: is both files uploaded to firebase storage?...please check

Comment: Thanks @JoseKj but it just uploaded the first file and the list is messed up thanks

Comment: which file got saved image or pdf ?tried the changes i made?......

Comment: It just saved the image @JoseKj thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was from the Book Service that image and pdf folder in firebase storage need to be seperate like below :

```
 addBook(bok: Book, cover: File, pdfFile: File) {
        if (this.uid != undefined && this.uid != null) {
            let key = this.afd.list('books' + '/' + 'list').$ref.ref.push().key;
            let userid = this.afAuth.auth.currentUser.uid;
            this.firebasestorage.ref(`cover` + `/` + key + `/` + this.currentUserId + bok.bookname).put(cover).then(
                snapshot => {
                    bok.cover = snapshot.downloadURL;      
                    this.afd.object('books/list' + '/' + key + this.currentUserId).set(bok);
                });
            this.firebasestorage.ref(`pdf` + `/` + key + `/` + this.currentUserId + bok.bookname).put(pdfFile).then(            
                snapshot => {
                    bok.file = snapshot.downloadURL;       
                    this.afd.object('books/list' + '/' + key + this.currentUserId).set(bok);
                    });    
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
 addBook(bok: Book, file: File, pdfFile: File) {
        if (this.uid != undefined && this.uid != null) {
            let key = this.afd.list('books' + '/' + 'list').$ref.ref.push().key;
            let userid = this.afAuth.auth.currentUser.uid;
            this.firebasestorage.ref(`books` + `/` + key + `/` + this.currentUserId + bok.bookname).put(file).then(
                snapshot => {
                    bok.icon = snapshot.downloadURL;
                    this.afd.object('books/list' + '/' + key + this.currentUserId).set(bok);
                });
             this.firebasestorage.ref(`books` + `/` + key + `/` + this.currentUserId + bok.bookname).put(pdfFile).then(
                 snapsht => {
                    bok.pdf = snapsht.downloadURL;     
                    this.afd.object('books/list' + '/' + key + this.currentUserId).set(bok);
                });
        }
    }
```